# Print invoice with wkhtmltopdf odoo 14 and centos 7

Tags: odoo, centos7, wkhtmltopdf

i get some warning when print invoice on odoo
warning message "Your installation of Wkhtmltopdf seems to be broken. The report will be shown in html."

[image: wkhtmltopdf in server centos7]
[image: warning on odoo]

i have follow this installation https://www.soladrive.com/support/knowledgebase/4997/How-to-install-WKHTMLTOPDF-for-Odoo.html

and this one https://www.soladrive.com/support/knowledgebase/4996/How-to-Install-Odoo-14-on-CentOS-7.html

but still get wkhtmltopdf broken

Answer (score 0):

Official Docs say it must be 0.12.5 [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/install.html) and you can use 0.12.5-1 version. Notably you get different layout between version numbers. Even if you can make it work, I suggest you use this version.